# Ble scans not received after turning the bluetooth off and turning it back on

Tags: java, c#, android, kotlin, xamarin.android

When the Bluetooth is turned On, I start ble scanning using `BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan (IList<ScanFilter> filters, ScanSettings settings, PendingIntent callbackIntent);` and I start receiving scans through a Broadcast receiver as expected.

Now, if I turn off the bluetooth on the phone, I stop receiving scans as expected but if I turn the bluetooth back on again I don't receive any scans.

Only after I have called `BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan` again, I start receiving scans again.

So it seems as if when the bluetooth is turned off and on, the state (the devices is scanning currently) is probably either never saved and restored, or the save or restore fails.

If, as per the design, we have to call `BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan` every single time the bluetooth turns on, we never get to know that bluetooth turned on when the app is not running, because the required implicit intent can no longer (Oreo+) be received through manifest declared broadcast receivers.

Do I necessarily have to call `BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan` every single time the bluetooth turns on? or am I missing on something?

Tried `BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan (IList<ScanFilter> filters, ScanSettings settings, PendingIntent callbackIntent);` to start scan.

Comment: ,It seems that the [Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le) can help you to scan